# Flask - jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm working on simple web using python flask. What I wanna do is actually really simple: I want to output "aaa" on the webpage on button click. Here's my HTML template (addUser.html):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="{{ url_for('route_add_user') }}" method="post" name="route_add_user">
        {{ form_add_user.hidden_tag() }}
        <h1>Create New User</h1>

        Username: <input type="text" name="username_add" placeholder="Username">

        <br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password_add" placeholder="Password">

        <br>
        Nama: <input type="text" name="name_add" placeholder="Name">

        <br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email_add" placeholder="E-mail">

        <br>
        Role:<select name="role_add">
            <option>Admin</option>
            <option selected="selected">User</option>
        </select>

        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add New User">
    </form>
</body>
```

And this one is the views (views.py):

```
@app.route('/route_add_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def route_add_user():
    iTemp_1 = 1
    form_add_user = AddUser()
    if form_add_user.validate_on_submit():
        if iTemp_1 == 1:
            return "aaa"
    return render_template('addUser.html', form_add_user = form_add_user)
```

And I got the error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form_add_user' is undefined
```

I'm pretty sure I've defined the "form_add_user". What did I miss?

Comment: Have you imported  the form `AddUser()` in your view?

Comment: Yes, I made the AddUser() class in forms.py and I have imported it in my view: from .forms import LoginForm, AddUser.

Comment: Are you using **Flask-WTF**?

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/route_add_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def route_add_user():
    iTemp_1 = 1
    form_add_user = AddUser()
    if form_add_user.validate_on_submit():
        if iTemp_1 == 1:
            flash('aaa')
    return render_template('addUser.html', form_add_user = form_add_user)
```